# Stop a jquery loop function on click while adding class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a function that continuously loops through a set of divs (see below) with the class active. I'm trying to modify the function so that when you click on the div it stops the loop and adds the class active to that div.

I've looked through countless examples on StackOverflow, but haven't been able to find something that works for my situation.

Function I'm trying to modify:

```
function doLoop() {
    $('.cd-types, .img-frame, .img-content-container').each(function(){
        (function($set){
            setInterval(function(){
                var $cur = $set.find('.active').removeClass('active');
                var $next = $cur.next().length ? $cur.next() : $set.children().eq(0);
                $next.addClass('active');
            },7000);
        })($(this));   
    });
}
```

Here is the [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/renevilla23/WpW8L/) with my attempt on modifying the loop. I know its fairly simple and I've spent the last few hours trying to figure it out. Any advice/direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: var tId = setInterval - now just call clearInterval(tId)

Comment: Hi @mplungjan - thanks for the speedy response. I tried this, but still having trouble. thoughts? [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/renevilla23/aMCK6/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
function doLoop() {
    $('.cd-types, .img-frame, .img-content-container, .list-items').each(function () {
        var $set = $(this);
        var interval = setInterval(function () {
            var $cur = $set.find('.active').removeClass('active');
            var $next = $cur.next().length ? $cur.next() : $set.children().eq(0);
            $next.addClass('active');
        }, 1000);
        $set.data('loop', interval);

        $set.on('click', '> *', function () {
            $(this).addClass('active').siblings('.active').removeClass('active');
            clearInterval($set.data('loop'));
            $set.removeData('loop')
        });
    });
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Ubh6T/), [Fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Ubh6T/2/)

Comment: Hi Arun - can you explain this line to me > '$set.on('click, '> *', function () )' What is the greater sign doing in the code. Thanks!

Comment: @user2647510 it is used to register the click handlers only to the direct children of the set element

Comment: great! Makes perfect sense. Thank you again - much appreciated!

Comment: Hi @Arun P Johny - i'm trying to modify the fiddle you above, with this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/renevilla23/3HPK5/), where you have three divs looping at the same time, but I'm having trouble making it so that they all stop at the same time when you click on one. Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

Simplified the loop function a bit to use the "self" variable trick.

timerID was used to track the setInterval() call so that it could be stopped using clearInterval() call when clicked:

```
$('.list-items').children().first().addClass('active');

var timerID;

$('.list-items').each(function () {
    var self = this;
    timerID = setInterval(function () {
        var $cur = $(self).find('.active').removeClass('active');
        var $next = $cur.next().length ? $cur.next() : $(self).children().eq(0);
        $next.addClass('active');
    }, 1000);
});

$('.list-items').on('click', function(){
    clearInterval(timerID);  
    alert("Stopped");
});
```

See the working code at:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rMpG3/4/)

Comment: thanks for the speedy response! This is close to what I was trying to achive, but its definitely in the right direction. I'm bookmarking this! Thanks again!